# Cassandra with docker swarm, "couldn't lookup host cassandra-seed"

Tags: cassandra, docker-swarm

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
   version: '3'
    services:  
      cassandra-seed:
        image: cassandra:latest
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
        ports:
          - "9042"
          - "7199"   
          - "9160"
          - "7000"
          - "7001"
        networks:
          default:
        volumes:
          - ./data:/var/lib/cassandra/data

      cassandra-node-1:
        image: cassandra:latest
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
        command: /bin/bash -c "echo 'Waiting for seed node' && sleep 120 && /docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f"
        environment:
          - "CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-seed"
        ports:
          - "9042"
          - "7199"   
          - "9160"
          - "7000"
          - "7001"

        networks:
          default:
        depends_on:
          - "cassandra-seed"

      cassandra-node-2:
        image: cassandra:latest
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
        command: /bin/bash -c "echo 'Waiting for seed node' && sleep 120 && /docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f"
        environment:
          - "CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-seed"
        depends_on:
          - "cassandra-seed"
        ports:
          - "9042"
          - "7199"   
          - "9160"
          - "7000"
          - "7001"
        networks:
          default:

    networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: cassandra-net
```

1. docker network create --scope swarm cassandra-net
2. Add all the nodes to the swarm
3. docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml cassandra-cluster

> WARN  [main] 2018-02-01 21:32:07,965 SimpleSeedProvider.java:60 - Seed provider couldn't lookup host cassandra-seed

Comment: Have you found a solution for that problem since over a year has passed already? When working with `docker-compose` I am having the same problem when scaling to a three node cluster. Strangely one additional node works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
- "CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-seed"
```

This is where you set the seed. The cassandra docker image entrypoint is expecting this value to be a comma-seperated list with IP addresses. You will have to find the ips somehow. I would recommend reading about [service discovery](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/#configure-service-discovery). Then create your own docker image with a custom  entrypoint where you set CASSANDRA_SEEDS by resolving the dns with 
the *host* command. You could also create a custom seed provider for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I think you shouldn't write

```
- "CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-seed"
```

instead, try this:

```
CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra-seed"
```

and also, if you want to make a cluster, you have to use the "CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS" as well.

For example:

```
environment:
  CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: cassandra-1
```

references:
https://dzone.com/articles/swarmweek-part-1-multi-host-cassandra-cluster-with
https://forums.docker.com/t/cassandra-on-docker-swarm/27923/3